# Change the text formation of a link inside an echo?

Tags: php, html

Here is my issue, I have this code to show a bunch of links that were uploaded by the user and display on the page, it works fine, but I want to edit the text font, color and size of the link, I tried putting a class inside the `echo`, but it didn't change the link formation, so I tried the `<H3>` element, but  it still didn't change, lastly I tried the `<div>` element, but I didn't have success again. So the code is as follows:

```
<h3 class="cor">
    <?php
        session_start();
        $email = $_SESSION['email'];
        require_once('conecta.php');
        $pasta = "uploads/";
        $objDb = new db();
        $link = $objDb->conecta_mysql();
        $consulta = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM arquivos WHERE email_vol = '$email'");
        while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
            $link = $pasta . $resultado["nomearq"];
            $descr = $resultado["dataup"]."   /   " . $resultado["nomearq"];

            echo "<a href='$link'>$descr</a><br>";
        } 
    ?>
</h3>
```

Can somebody give me a hand? Thank you so much!

Comment: `echo "<a href='$link' class='some-class'>$descr</a><br>";` - then style `a.some-class {...}` through css. If it doesn't work, the issue is else where and not in the php/html-markup.

Comment: Try `echo "<a class=myclass href='$link'>$descr</a><br>"; `  and  in style `.myclass{ color:red; font-size:32px; }`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson do you know if i had to call the css page inside the php tags? Or if i just call in the `<head>` it should work?

Comment: The css should be called as usual in the head-tag with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/your/style.css" >`. PHP gets parsed on the server and will, in this case, just generate HTML that gets sent to the client (browser). So as far as the browser is concerned, it only gets an ordinary HTML-document. PHP and CSS are totally unrelated.

Comment: @AdhershMNair Thank you so much man, it works just fine. But i had to ask you, has difference of putting the `<class>` before or after the link? And why without quotes?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Understood man, thank you so much!

Comment: You can put the class attribute where ever inside the tag, before, after, it's the same. The order of html-attributes doesn't matter. It's recommended to always use quotes for arguments, since `class=firstClass secondClass` would, for example, not work while `class='firstClass secondClass'` would. It's best to be consistent.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You Are Right.!

Comment: I hope this isn't a live site here. You're open to an sql injection.

Comment: and you stand at outputting before header.

Comment: @Fred-ii- what?

Comment: Errrr. what, what? *lol!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- How can I prevent this Sql Injection, i'm doing some searchs about it, i never heard about it

Comment: Google just that: *How can I prevent this Sql Injection* ;-) you'll find many hits and many of them leading back here to Stack.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Okay man, thank you so much for the tips, i'm really noob at those things, trying to learn now!

Comment: you're most welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`echo "<a class=myclass href='$link'>$descr</a><br>";`

and in style

```
.myclass{ 
       color:red; 
       font-size:32px; 
}
```

Comment: As @MagnusEriksson said "The order of html-attributes doesn't matter. But when you have multiple classes for a single element you must add quotes to them."